# K800i 5.2 mm lens equivalent

Tags: lens

I really like the pictures my Sony K800i with its 5.2mm lens takes and I use its lofi quality to creative effect and woud like to know the 35 mm lens equivalent to this little piece of plastic.

I looked at pictures from the Ricoh GR Digital with its fixed 28mm lens, but it doesn't have the same flatness or shallowness.

Since its a 5.2 mm lens, can there actually be a 35mm lens equivalent that captures everything this way? Or do angles, light and what not just get bent in a very unique way when using such a small lens - that a bigger one actually could not reproduce the exact same look?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're looking for when you say "35mm equivalent"? I'm assuming what you're looking for is a larger, fancier camera than your camera phone, but you want to get a similar aesthetic?

Comment: Maybe useful background reading: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/139/5551

Comment: If you want poor image quality I have a drawer full of lenses I'll happily sell you.

Comment: @mattdm digital cameras that have a smaller sensor usually give a crop factor - so one can determine what kind effect the lens produces compared to a 35mm (or digita fullframe i guess) camera produces. For Example: The Sigma DP2 has a a fixed 24.2mm f/2.8 lens but review say its a (41mm equivalent).

So what I want to know is what kind of lens I would have to buy for a Fullframe camera, that would produce the same pictures from a "perspective" point of view (of course noise, color rendition, sharpness and so on will all be better/different).

Comment: Oh -- so is your question really just "what's the crop factor of the K800i?" I based my answer on a web search result that says the camera has a 50° field of view — roughly a 35mm lens on a 35mm-full-frame camera.

Comment: I think the question is, assuming that on a full frame camera, a 35mm lens is the equivalent of this 5.2mm lens on the Sony, will the 35mm full frame give a similar result in terms of perspective, field of view etc.  OR can the 5.2mm, being much physically smaller, produce quite different images to its full frame "equivalent"

Comment: thanks mike, that is actually exactly what I am interested in.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you might be after here could be provided by something in the [Lensbaby](http://lensbaby.com/) lineup. This is a series of interchangeable lenses for SLR and mirrorless cameras which have a "lo-fi" look. Particularly, the [plastic optic](http://lensbaby.com/optics-plastic) may appeal to you. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "flatness or shallowness", but you can see some sample photos in the [sample gallery](http://lensbaby.com/gallery-photos?o=plastic) or [on flickr](http://lensbaby.com/gallery-photos?o=plastic).

This optic gives a narrower field of view than your cameraphone lens. The Lensbaby plastic optic focal length is roughly 50mm, so on a typical entry or mid-level DSLR, combining it with the [Lenbaby Super Wide adapter](http://lensbaby.com/accessories-superwideangle) will give you approximately the same framing you are used to. (The K800i has a field of view of about 50°; depending on the exact sensor size of the camera body you choose, the plastic optic + super wide will be between 45° and 60°. Plus, of course, you'll have the option of *not* using the adapter to get a longer focal length, in the traditional portrait range.)

Lensbaby produces what they call "lens bodies" to hold various swappable optics, each with a different look. The entry-level "Muse" used to be available for $100 with the plastic optic, but it looks now like they're only selling a $150 pair with the double-glass optic, and then the plastic optic as a $40 add-on. You might enjoy both, so that's not necessarily a bad thing. (You might even want the whole selection of single glass, plastic, and pinhole/[zone-plate](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/what-is-a-zone-plate).)

The lens bodies come in versions for Canon, Nikon, Sony, Pentax (which will also work on Sigma), and Olympus/Panasonic Four Thirds mount. So, you could pair this with any entry-level dSLR, but it's also worth considering the mirrorless options — I think Lensbaby plus Olympus Pen is a pretty sweet setup, and you can get, for example, the EP-2 for under $250.

On the issue of whether you can get *exactly* the same look, in short, no. Generally, every lens design has a different rendering, regardless of size. Specifically, the small lens and small imaging circle result in a large depth of field, and relatively pronounced limitation on sharpness due to diffraction — roughly like a wide-angle 35mm full-frame lens stopped down to f/22.

Using the Lensbaby plastic optic, dropping in one of the smaller aperture disks should give a similar effect. You'll need to either increase shutter speed to get the right exposure, or — actually — probably both. But one of the advantages of using a larger camera system for lo-fi photography like this is that you get to make more choices about where you want to make those compromises.

Comment: thanks for the advice and explanation matt!

So its a combination of field of view, lens width and depth of field that produces the look I suppose? 
I looked into the Lensbaby, but I don't really like the vignette effect and find don't find it pleasing to artificially downgrade a system to look worse.

Comment: @Roland: the cool thing about the Lensbaby is that it's _not_ artificially "downgrading" the system, like Instagram or something like that. It's getting the best possible out of a non-typical type of lens.

Comment: Also: if you use one of the smaller aperture rings, there will not be a significant vignetting effect.

Comment: But given your answers here, I'm still puzzled by exactly what you're looking for. Sounds like you really like the look of your K800i photos; why not just stay with that?