# Bokeh on a 55 mm lens

Tags: canon, bokeh

I am an aspiring photographer and I was wondering if it is possible to get bokeh images with a 55 mm lens since right now that is all I have.

Comment: Also see [What is bokeh, exactly?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2706/1943)

Comment: The aperture of your lens is more important than the focal length. What specific lens are you using?

Comment: and the optical characteristics of the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh is the quality of the shape of a point of light which has become enlarged against a darker background due to its being out of focus. Perfect bokeh is usually considered to be when these points are rendered as perfectly round discs with a uniform brightness across the whole disc.

Usually the quality of bokeh produced by a lens depends on the number of aperture blades and the refinement of the lenses. For example, a lens which uses only five aperture blades tends to produce pentagonal shapes rather than discs (which is usually considered poor bokeh).

The size of such an unfocused point of light depends on the depth of field, and this depends on the aperture of the lens. A lens operating at a large aperture (such as f/1.4) will produce unfocused points of light to be rendered much larger than a lens using a small aperture (such as f/8.0).

So the bokeh which can be produced by your lens depends on the maximum aperture, and the number of aperture blades, and on the quality of the glass used in the lens. You don't say which specific lens you have, so you might need to provide more information. But if you hunt online for reviews of your exact model of lens you will probably find detailed examinations of the bokeh it produces.