# Why does a larger aperture cause more blur of the background?

Tags: aperture, depth-of-field, blur, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Technically, why is the out of focus area blurred more when using a bigger aperture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/technically-why-is-the-out-of-focus-area-blurred-more-when-using-a-bigger-apert)

Why is it that a larger lens aperture produces a shorter depth of field, causing the background of a photo to be more blurred?