# What is Aperture in Camera?

Tags: aperture

This is first of my few questions coming up on cameras. I cannot ask all in one question as they relate to different topics.

My first question:

> What is Aperture in Camera?

Why Having a bigger aperture makes images blurred?

Can anyone clear my question? I read it on some blogs and wiki, but they are all to confusing to me. It is too complicated on Wiki for me to understand it.

Comment: Also see [Technically, why is the out of focus area blurred more when using a bigger aperture?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/technically-why-is-the-out-of-focus-area-blurred-more-when-using-a-bigger-apert)

Comment: Hopefully, some of the existing answers on those posts will be easier to understand than previous references. If not, please give some detail into exactly what is confusing or unclear. Also, thanks for separating your questions on different topics into different posts. That's absolutely the right way to do it.

Comment: @mattdm Thank you very much Mat. I will read them and see if it clears my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aperture is basically the size of the opening within your lens through which light is allowed to reach the sensor (or film) of your camera.

This size is measured as f-number (for example f/2.8, f/4, f/5.6, etc...). the lower the number the bigger the opening. And yes, you can assume that bigger the opening (or aperture) more blurred area in the pic.

Smaller aperture helps you keep more area in the pic as sharp and wider one will tend to have only the focus plane as sharp and will blur the rest.

Also just for your knowledge, the blurry thing in a pic (given that the area of interest is sharp and in focus) is called Bokeh.

I hope this helps!

Thanks,
Pranet.

Comment: This is a nit, but aperture isn't the size of the opening; it _is_ the opening. And along time same lines, bokeh isn't the blur or the blurry area — it is a word which describes the _quality_ of the blur. (More on that [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/48478/1943)).

Comment: @mattdm, um, not [according to Mike Johnston](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2009/01/what-is-bokeh.html), the guy who introduced/popularized the spelling as "bokeh" (vs. _boke_) in _Photo Technique_ magazine: "..."Bokeh" simply means blur, specifically out-of-focus blur ..."  _Boke-aji_ is the term for the flavor of the blur.

Comment: @inkista  But we don't really use "boke-aji" in English; we use "blur" to mean "blur", and "bokeh" to mean the "flavor of the blur". This corresponds to Mike Johnston's use in practice; see [The New King of Bokeh](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2016/05/open-mike-new-king-of-bokeh.html).