# Depth of field and aperture size

Tags: lens, aperture, depth-of-field

Why does a smaller aperture size have a high depth of field? What is the physics behind this?

Comment: @PhilipKendall This isn't a duplicate. The linked answer states the aperture results in DoF but this person already knows it, and is asking about the physics behind it.

Comment: @HairyDresden - a) the OP has the premise in reverse & b) did you look at the 2nd answer on the dupe?

Comment: We _do_ have [the technical question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13456/1943) too.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does a smaller aperture size have a low depth of field?

It doesn't; you've got it backward. Decreasing aperture size *increases* depth of field.

What might be confusing you is that smaller f-numbers indicate larger apertures. For example, an aperture setting of f/2 indicates a larger aperture than does f/2.8.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry my bad!